# my freezer popped open without my knowlege

Tags: food-safety, freezing, thawing

my freezer popped open without my knowledge, not sure when, but it was no longer than a day and a half,  there was ice formed on the roof and the sides, is it safe to refreeze?  I had hamburger, steak and green beans in there.
bobbi

Comment: What temperature are the things?  If they're to fridge temp, you might be better off moving them to the fridge, and using them soon.  Freeze/thaw cycles can do bad things to most uncooked things.  (and even some cooked ones).

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Perhaps it would help us all of you give us some more detail on the exact state of the products when you discovered the open freezer. Were they still frozen solid, or did they really start to thaw?